# Getting started page missing after deploying java play application to heroku

Tags: java, heroku, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.1

I recently deployed my java play application (2.1.3) to heroku. Everything appears to go smoothly. But when I access the site on the heroku server, the getting started template that I see when running the project from my local machine is missing. Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you did not add some files (say, your template) to git, so they were not pushed to Heroku?